# On the performance of QQuickPaintedItem and scaling

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a custom `QQuickPaintedItem` in my app and now I am wondering on a way to properly scale the item I have created. In the "Qt Widgets world", there was `QGraphicsView` and its performance was very good, but it seems that `QQuickPaintedItem` cannot match its performance. I know that you can subclass `QQuickItem` directly and then using the QML scene graph I can use OpenGL (which I am not really familiar with at all) to render the item, however that is not an option for me. 
What I would like to investigate is if it was possible to efficiently scale a QQuickPaintedItem, specifically once I drawn the item then I can use the `scale` property in QML, however this scales the whole item (hence making it blurry), instead I would like to scale the content of the item but how can I do that efficiently? In the examples offered in Qt Creator, there is [SvgViewer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtsvg-svgviewer-example.html) which shows how a `QGraphicsView` can be used to show an SVG image and scale it "perfectly". Is this sort of behaviour obtainable in QML?

EDIT: The source of the performance issues is that `QQuickPaintedItem` does not use the QSG and hence it has to rasterize and then paint items. This results in the fact that when scaling, one has to redraw the item when is scaled. As you can imagine, when redrawing everything every few ms can be very costly

Comment: Ok, first of all you didn't provide the source, maybe the possible performance issue is in the code. The second, as you've already noticed, `QQuickPaintedItem` is always a losing option unlike `QQuickItem` since you draw the item twice.

Comment: @folibis yes you are right, the best option seems to be a custom `QQuickItem` however the api it provides is very low level and really hard to use. I am looking for an alternative. In pure C++, I can use `QGraphicsView` which has decent performance, but in QML world there doesn't really seem to be something analogous.